# get strings in array from another string by matching pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like follows:

```
$str = "`col1` int(4) NOT NULL,`column2` varchar(45),`someothercol` text,";
```

I want the list of column names i.e. anything that exists between

```
 `**`
```

The array should consist

```
array("col1","column2","someothercol");
```

Comment: show your efforts

Comment: I have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$str = "`col1` int(4) NOT NULL,`column2` varchar(45),`someothercol` text,";
$arr = preg_match_all('/`(\w+)`/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => col1
    [1] => column2
    [2] => someothercol
)
```